# Notepadd++ Regex replace character equal to in certain position

Tags: regex, notepad++

can someone help me with a Notepad++ Regex to replace characters in certain positions? I know there is a lot of answers related to regex, but I'm having a hard time with this, so I apologize if this is a duplicate. Below is what I need done..

Below is a text fixed file where I need to: 
1) Replace characters in position 1-3 equal to "622" and replace with "633".
2) Replace characters in position 35-42 to zeroes.
This is before:

```
622021000021833364532        00000202050007037174     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294578
6240631075131010089984136    00000162050006912435     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294622
6242631830492020236          00000025000006912435     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294622
6222631830492020257          00000015000006912435     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294581
6220610001041000142074458    00000202050500002543     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294582
```

This should be after:

```
623021000021833364532        00000000000007037174     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294578
6240631075131010089984136    00000000000006912435     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294622
6242631830492020236          00000000000006912435     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294622
6232631830492020257          00000000000006912435     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294581
6230610001041000142074458    00000000000000002543     JOHN SMITH              0043000264294582
```

Below is what I have so far for request 1:
Find: ^(.{3})
This finds the first 3 characters, but I need to find the first 3 characters = to "622". 
I can't just find "622" because line 2 and 3 have "622" near the end. Those should not be replaced.

Can someone help me with both requests? Any help is much appreciated! 
Thank you! - Remo

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: For the first question: Find `^622` replace: `633`

Comment: I just edited the post to show what I have so far. Also, the ^622 seems to work! Is there a way to find 622 for positions 1-3? Thank you!

Comment: `^622` IS the way to find `622` at the begining of the line.

Comment: For `35-42` it's find `^(.{34}).{7}` replace `${1}0000000` (multi-line mode). Both regex are run separately, and once.

Comment: Thank you Toto and sln!!! Both work perfect! Thanks again for your time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find `^622` replace: `633`
2. For `35-42` it's find `^(.{34}).{7}` replace `${1}0000000` (multi-line mode). Both regex are run separately, and once.